# Parsing a tab-delimited .txt into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, string, dataframe, csv

I have a tab delimited .txt file that I'm trying to import into a dataframe in Python of the same format as the text file is as shown below:

ham ***TAB*** Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...

spam  ***TAB***   Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup final tkts 21st May 2005. Text FA to 87121 to receive entry question(std txt rate)T&C's apply 08452810075over18's

...

Note there are many, many more rows of the stuff above (roughly 5500) that I want to pass into Python and maintain the same formatting when creating a matrix array from it.

The current code that I have for this is:

```
 import pandas as pd 

 with open("SMSSpamCollection.txt") as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
      d = list(reader)
 d = pd.DataFrame(reader)
```

Which it slightly does what I need it to do, but I want a DataFrame with 2 columns: Y (containing ham or spam) and a second X (containing the message). At this time I get a [5572,2] DataFrame.

Comment: You're working much harder than you need to. [Pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) handles all the file context management and reading with hardly any tuning nevessary, but lots of tuning available

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd 
d = pd.read_csv("SMSSpamCollection.txt", sep="\t", names=['Y','X'])
```