# string into dict of list - python

Tags: python, string, python-tesseract

I am trying to figure out the best way to parse the string you get from using `pytesseract.image_to_data("image.png")`.

When I usually get databack it comes out like this:

```
level   page_num    block_num   par_num line_num    word_num    left    top width   height  conf    text
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1920    1080    -1  
2   1   1   0   0   0   0   8   28  17  -1  
3   1   1   1   0   0   0   8   28  17  -1  
4   1   1   1   1   0   0   8   28  17  -1  
5   1   1   1   1   1   0   8   28  17  95.000000    
2   1   2   0   0   0   15  9   737 52  -1  
3   1   2   1   0   0   15  9   737 52  -1  
4   1   2   1   1   0   15  9   438 19  -1  
5   1   2   1   1   1   15  9   10  9   27.712341   |
5   1   2   1   1   2   31  10  58  14  96.167610   Tableau
5   1   2   1   1   3   96  10  46  14  92.450928   Public
5   1   2   1   1   4   148 18  5   1   92.450928   -
5   1   2   1   1   5   160 11  66  13  96.975945   Business
5   1   2   1   1   6   231 10  84  18  93.306007   Ownership
5   1   2   1   1   7   322 18  5   1   92.816788   -
5   1   2   1   1   8   334 11  56  13  96.618721   Section
etc.....
```

But I would like the data to come out in a list/dict so I can search for the `width` and `height` based on the `text` value.
so I know would like to do something like:

```
data = pytesseract.image_to_data("image.png")
for rows in data:
    if "Public" in rows["text"]:
        print(rows["width"])
        print(rows["height"])
```

but since the data comes out as a string, I am not sure how to do what I am looking for.

I tried seeing if pytesseract had a way to parse the image in question to the list/dict structure I am looking for but no luck as of yet. Also parsing seems to be hard as I THINK its a string that is separated by tabs?

Is there anyway to convert a pytesseract image into a list/array so I can pull the specific information I want from it?

Comment: Is the output a string or a pandas data frame?

You can [pass parameters to image_to_data()](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) like: `image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT)`, but I'd guess that still wouldn't be what you want....but a pandas data frame might be easier to use than trying to parse a string.

Comment: @shawncaza I wish it was a df, then I can atleast google some stuff. I know I have used pandas sparingly in the past and i would rather use that. However, I am pretty sure its a string because when I did `print(type(data))` on it earlier, it came back as a string. I also opened it with libre office and also imported it into excel and it seems to take it in as tab delemeted data.... which I am not sure how to parse given the knowledge I have.

Comment: Did you try `image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT)`? Maybe that is what you want. If you'd prefer a df then I'd try `image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DATAFRAME)`

Comment: To read tab delimited data you could use pandas or maybe the csv libraries. [Here's a basic pandas example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572065/1586014).

Documentation on [pandas read_csv is here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)

Comment: Hahahaha I was coming back here to write an answer as I just figured it out and low and behold you had the same thing as me `mage_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT)` - I was looking for that found it about 10 minutes ago. It works because the dictionaries are parallel with one another so I can use each column with its index. AWESOME

Comment: Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer at the same time @shawncaza did. The function for `image_to_data` has a param option for output type which you can set to dict. Here is a basic example of how to convert this type of string into a dict/list:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

data = pytesseract.image_to_data("image.png", output_type=Output.DICT)
print(data)
```